# How to let a role handle media without post permissions

Tags: attachments, capabilities, permissions

I have a CPT to replace my "post"-post-type, but I still need to be able to use attachments. The problem is, that attachments have the post-capabilities.

I don’t want to give post capabilities to my role, because of that, I tried to find a way to avoid it.

I found a hack in the wordpress track:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19834

```
function crunchhack() {
   global $wp_post_types;
   $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->edit_post = 'upload_files';
}
add_action( 'init', 'crunchhack' );
```

I have added it to my `functions.php`. It did not work, because of that, I tried to replace all post-capabilities of the attachment post-type with `upload_files`:

```
function fix_media_permissions() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->edit_post = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->read_post = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->delete_post = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->edit_posts = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->edit_others_posts = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->edit_published_posts = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->publish_posts = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->delete_posts = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->delete_others_posts = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->delete_published_posts = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->delete_private_posts = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->edit_private_posts = 'upload_files';
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->cap->read_private_posts = 'upload_files';
}
add_action( 'init',  'fix_media_permissions');
```

Sadly this doesn’t work either. I can see the uploaded images, but that’s it. Any ideas?

Comment: Im curious, why did you replace the perfectly good posts post type with a whole new post type? Was there something that prevented you using multisite or custom taxonomies?

Comment: I needed a post type with a custom meta box with a list that handles the attachments of this post. Looking back now, it might have been easier to try to alter the posts post type, but it seamed easier to create a new post type for it.

Comment: It is pretty easy, almost trivial, to add meta_boxes.

Comment: There are plugins that will do the work for you even, for the most part its a copy paste affair out of the codex

Comment: The problem in altering the "post" post-type is, that if I want to use it in addition to the new post-type, altering the original is no option.  
Creating the post-type never was a problem, I struggled with the permissions. I didn’t want to use plugins, because I am trying to understand how things work in Wordpress.  
Anyway, I solved it and everything works like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was, that I called the function inside of another function, called later. The snippet in the question works like it should.

I thought about deleting the question, but I think for other users, that are searching for a way to do something like that, the snippet would be interesting.